# Picking selected mesh from an OBJ file

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm using the OBJLoader to load a large 3D model (described in a .obj file) but it loads the whole file as a single Object3D object. Using scene.add(object) it adds the whole object to the scene.

I need to pick the selected mesh and change some of its properties, but when I add mouse function and use Ray.intersectObjects try to get the selected mesh it never works. I can not find where I made mistakes.

Would love some help with trying to get this working. Thanks!

It confused me for couples of days. The following is all my code：

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - loaders - OBJ loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js" target="_blank">three.js</a> - OBJLoader test
        </div>

        <script src="../build/Three.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/Stats.js"></script>

        <script>

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            var _mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 },
                objects = [],
                _projector = new THREE.Projector();


            init();
            animate();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 100;
                scene.add( camera );

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x101030 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffeedd );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 ).normalize();
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/ash_uvgrid01.jpg' );

                var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                loader.load( "obj/male02/male02.obj", function ( object ) {

                    for ( var i = 0, l = object.children.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

                        object.children[ i ].material.map = texture;

                    }

                    object.position.y = - 80;
                    object.position.z = - 160;
                    scene.add( object );
                    objects.push( object );

                } );

                // RENDERER

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();

                // find intersections
                _mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
                _mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

                var vector = new THREE.Vector3( _mouse.x, _mouse.y, 1 );

                var ray = _projector.pickingRay( vector, camera );

                var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( scene.children );

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                        alert("selected!");
                        _SELECTED_DOWN = true;
                }   
            }

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );
                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

`ray.intersectObjects()` is not recursive. You need to pass a list of the objects you want to test.

Comment: however, maybe I should change it to `ray.intersectObjects( array, recursive )`...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but I still do not get it. You mean the parameters（ scene.children ） that I pass are not a list of the objects. Then how should I change it ?

Comment: Try using this build: https://raw.github.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/Three.js and do `ray.intersectObjects( scene.children, true )`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried your solution but it still did not work.I'm going crazy! My following work are based on this. I can not go further if I could not solve this problem.

Comment: Can you upload your test somewhere so it can be analysed?

Comment: Not really. You'd have to upload the working test somewhere. Maybe using a dropbox public folder?

Comment: I put my code on drop.Here is the link![https://www.dropbox.com/sh/12x6lix669j6ssd/5k6K20K3aW](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/12x6lix669j6ssd/5k6K20K3aW)@mrdoob

Comment: Hmmm, try implementing this from scratch using the latest code in the dev branch. https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/zipball/dev

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution and patience. Finally it works and I am so exciting. Thanks again!